# android code dial out pause in number

Tags: android

I am writing some app to access my voicemail. I have an access number, and when I call it I must wait for 6 sec and then enter my PIN. The Android still doesn't have the API to `sendDTMF`, so I must use pauses in calling number.

I have searched the internet and find that I can enter `,` (comma) or `p` for one second pause. But on Android emulator this don't work, e.g., when using comma, I dial `<access_number>,,,,,,<PIN_number>,` and on emulator I only see that `<access_number>` is dialed. When using `p`, I see that access number and PIN concatenated `<access_number><PIN_number>`.

How can I make some pause?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here is my solution (Tested on Android4.0.1):

```
    /**
 * Dials a number with DTMF chars
 * Note: When the number is dialed, only the initial number is displayed on the device dialer
 * For example: dial("*6900,,,3") will display only *6900 on the device dialer (but the rest will also be processed)
 * @param number
 */
public void dial(String number) {
    try {
        number = new String(number.trim().replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26")
                .replace(",", "%2c").replace("(", "%28").replace(")", "%29")
                .replace("!", "%21").replace("=", "%3D").replace("<", "%3C")
                .replace(">", "%3E").replace("#", "%23").replace("$", "%24")
                .replace("'", "%27").replace("*", "%2A").replace("-", "%2D")
                .replace(".", "%2E").replace("/", "%2F").replace(":", "%3A")
                .replace(";", "%3B").replace("?", "%3F").replace("@", "%40")
                .replace("[", "%5B").replace("\\", "%5C").replace("]", "%5D")
                .replace("_", "%5F").replace("`", "%60").replace("{", "%7B")
                .replace("|", "%7C").replace("}", "%7D"));

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode(number));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, uri);
        startActivity(intent);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //getAlertDialog().setMessage("Invalid number");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```